# jquery .resize() not working for small width

Tags: jquery, firefox, resize

I'm trying to make a menu that has different states depending of the width of the browsers. 
For this feature I'm using $(window).resize() to listen the resize event.
It works ok on chrome, but on firefox the event is not triggered if the width is less than 320px.

Any ideea why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645649) which has to do with the size of the navigation bar (with the back button etc.).

Note also that if you change the height when resizing, an event will still fire even if the width is smaller than ~300px, but the reported width remains the same.